# namespace, классы и сокращение синтаксиса

Tags: c++

Я перехожу из java в c++, в java каждый каталог - это пакет, тоже самое что namespace.

Когда что то пишу на c++ я поступаю так же, допустим blabla/math/
и все классы, которые там находится, в пространстве имен blabla::math.
Есть проблема, нельзя написать

```
namespace blabla::math { }
```

Только так

```
namespace blabla 
{
   namespace math 
   {
   }
}
```

Когда вложенных namespace-ов больше, выглядит еще более некрасиво. Если ли способ сократить запись именно в таком случае?

Comment: Можно использовать using namespace <name>, либо обращаться через <name>::<что-то>. А вообще не пытайтесь копировать идеологию Java в C++.

Comment: @carapuz А как правильней разбивать проект на namespacы?

Comment: Вы делаете нормально, это никак не противоречит идеологии C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете писать

```
namespace blabla { namespace math {

}}
```

Других способов на данный момент нет.

В следующей версии С++ будут модули (через два года минимум), но и они не отменяют namespace.

Comment: Но мы ждём появления [нового](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html) синтаксиса

Answer (score -1):

Можно заменить на `define`

```
#define             NS_FOO_START            namespace Foo {
#define             NS_FOO_END              }
#define             NS_FOO_USING            using namespace Foo;
```

как сделано в движке cocos2dx